# The += operator

Tags: java, javascript, operators

I got a question concerning the `+=` operator.
I have the task to check which value `j` has at the end. Now, I already have run it through Java and got the results but I don't really get how the solution is brought together. I hope someone can explain to me how it is established:

(1)

```
for (i = 10, j = 1; i > 0; i = i - 2)
    j += j;
```

Solution: j = 32

(2)

```
for (j = 0, i = 0; j < 10; j = j + i, i++)
    j += j;
```

Solution: j = 11

(3)

```
for (i = 0, j = 10; i < 10 && j > 5; i++)
    j += j-- + i++;
```

Solution: j = 372

Comment: Java or Javascript? Pick one and remove the tag for the other

Comment: Write it down on paper and see for yourself. Be the computer.

Comment: If you're writing stuff like `j += j-- + i++` you deserve all the pain that comes of it.

Comment: @MarcB best comment ever on the SO.

Comment: Well, homework is cruel. ~

Comment: add a print in the for loop before and after the operation to see yourself how things work.

Comment: @musefan: Although it happens, in this case, not really to matter. But yes, best not to (further) confuse those two largely-unrelated languages. :-)

Comment: You can step through the code in your debugger and see what each line does.

Comment: I will not post this as an answer. But for the low level of knowledge of the OP it worth at least explain how he can understand. So, It seems that you dont even know how a `for` works but for understand what is going on you can put some out put for every iteration and see what is going on with every variable. If this is javascrip you can add `alert(j)` or/and `alert(i)` after each attribuition in the for statement if it is java you can add a `System.out.println(i);` and see it for yourself

Comment: Nobody should have to know that! Because it's nonsense! You (hopefully) will NEVER EVER write code like that. Even 'i = i++' is a no-no. And you should also never modify the for-loop counter variable in the body of the loop.

Comment: This task was not supposed to make sense, I guess. It was made to make us understand what happens there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
j += j;
```

is the same as

```
j = j + j;
```

that is to say, it adds to j, everything after the  '+=' so

```
j += j + j-- + i++;
```

is the same as

```
j = j + (j--) + (i++);
```

or

```
j = j + j + i; //the ++ adds one to i and the -- takes one from j after this statement has ran
```

Comment: AFAIK `j = j + (j--) + (i++);` would be equal to `j = j + j + i - 1` (i being incremented after that)

Comment: (j--) is not equal to (j - 1) in this case. It decrements j but returns the undecremented value.

Comment: I obviously wasn't paying attention, thanks for the correction.  You are of course right.

Comment: thanks!
wouldn't the solution to the first task simply be:
j = 1 + 1 = 2

The outcome says it's 32 but "i" isn't even brought in this calculation, right?

Comment: The first one steps i from 10 to 0.  Taking two steps each time (thats 5 steps).  Every time it does this it adds j to itself. 
Add j (1) to itself 5 times and you get 1+1=2, 2+2=4, 4+4=8, 8+8=16, 16+16=32

Comment: great, i think i got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's unroll `j += j-- + i++`.

- `j--` returns the value of j and decrements j afterward, i.e. if j is 2, then 2 is returned and j is 1 afterward
- `i++` is the same but i is incremented afterward
- `j-- + i++` yields thus the same result as `j + i` (besides that j and i are changed as well).
- after those operations `j` would be decremented, hence `j += j-- + i++` is equal to `j = (j - 1) + (j + i)`

Note that order is important, i.e. `j + j--` yields the same result as `j + j` but the result of `j-- + j` would be `j + j - 1` (because j is returned, then decremented, then added).

As for the rest of your code, just look at how variables are changed over the course of time. I'll expand your second one as an example:

```
for (j = 0, i = 0; j < 10; j = j + i, i++)
   j += j;
```

The loop initializes j with 0 and each iteration first doubles j (`j += j`) then adds i and increments i (`j = j + i, i++`).

Hence iteration 1 will yield `j = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0`. (i is 1 now)
Iteration 1 will yield `j = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1`. (i is 2 now)
Iteration 2 will yield `j = 1 + 1 + 2 = 4`. (i is 3 now)
Iteration 3 will yield `j = 4 + 4 + 3 = 11`. (i is 4 now)

Answer (score 0):

The += is really easy to understand. Basically whatever is on the right hand is added to whatever is on the left hand.

Its maybe the pre-increment and post-increment that can be confusing. Basically the pre-increment will add one to the value and THEN perform the other operations in order of precedence, whereas a post-increment will perform the other operations in order of precedence BEFORE incrementing.

So for example

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
int k = 2;

i += j++ + k++; 

System.out.println("i: " + i);

/* i is 4 because it added the value of j BEFORE incrementing j(value of 1)
 * and added the value of k  *BEFORE incrementing k(value of 2) After the values 
 * have been added to i, they then become 2 and 3 respectively
 */

System.out.println("j: " + j); 

//j was one, but is now 2 because it incremented after adding its  value to i

System.out.println("k: " + k); 
//k was two, but is now 3 because it incremented after adding its value to i

i = 0; //reset i to 0 but leave k at 3, then...

i += ++k; 

System.out.println("i: " + i);

//i is now 4 because k was pre-incremented from 3 to 4 BEFORE assigning its value to i

i = 0; //reset i to 0 again
i += k++;

System.out.println("i: " + i);

//i is still 4 because k post-incremented AFTER assigning its value to i
```